# Using the CharAt and length methods

Tags: java, string

I am trying to write a method for a class StringAmmount.

The method is int count(String s, char ch) that counts how many times the character ch appears in the string s, and returns that count.

Comment: Do you have a specific question about the method?

Comment: So write some code, show us what you have done.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking to write code.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int count( String s, char ch )
{
    int occurrences = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i )
        if ( s.charAt(i) == ch )
            ++occurrences;   

    return occurrences;     
}
```

You could store s.length() in a variable before entering the for loop so you don't make the function call on every iteration.  It's a ~very~ small optimization, but it is an optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as simple as -

```
public int count(String s, char ch)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i <s.length();i++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i) == ch)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
private int count(String s, char ch) {
    int index = s.indexOf(ch);
    int count = 0;
    while (index != -1) {
        count++;
        s = s.substring(index + 1);
        index = s.indexOf(ch);
    }
    System.out.println("No of " + ch +" in the input is : " + count);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: What if I called: `count("this",'t')`- you can't just assume `s` won't contain "is"

Comment: Not to mention the user wanted to use the String class's charAt() and length() methods, and you used neither.